# Dot plus (".+") notation in json schema; what does it mean?

Tags: java, json, schema

I'm working with a draft-06 schema and have seen markup that's new to me:

```
"properties":{
  ".+":{
    "type":"string"
  }
},
```

What does the ".+" signify?  Is this why, for example, jsonschema2pojo won't generate Java from this?

Comment: By looking at your problem I am not quite sure but I think it is a `regex` denoting json object of type String which has every character except for the line terminator(`\n` for instance)!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so by looking at your `json` I can figure it out that(a **json-schema validator**) the String represents a regular expression which denotes the `"type":"String"` of the JSON object can contain every character except for the **line terminators**(say `\n`).

The above `regex` will be applied to each and every `json object` of type `properties`. You can also get a better insight from the answer mentioned in [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786433/regex-to-match-nested-json-objects).
You can also refer [**this**](https://epoberezkin.github.io/ajv/keywords.html) link to enhance your understanding better about the use of `JSON regex`.

Regards :)