# How to make a recursive Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to create a regex that is able to match some logical formulas for me, to validate an input.

Basically, I will have a number(0-100), a key word(AND/OR) and parenthesis.

So I should be able to match such kinds of use cases:

```
1 AND 2
(1 AND 2) OR 3
1 AND (2 OR 3)
(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)
1 AND (2 OR (3 AND (4 OR 5)))
```

I don't need to validate its the simpliest form(like preventing the user to write `(1 AND (2 AND 3))`.

So far I've created this:

```
\(?(\d+)\s+(AND|OR)\s+\d+\)?
```

But I'm stuck on several things:

1. Is there some way of doing recursive things with regex(in C#)? Because I should not be limiting the parenthesis level. the goal would be to have either `\d+` either the same whole expression
2. I'm not sure how to enforce that if a open parenthesis was added, I should also have a closing parenthesis?

Comment: IMHO writing a parser and checking if the expression can be parsed should yield faster results and better maintainable code than an over-complicated regex that may or may not be possible.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann You're correct, but it's more to better understand regex and to learn.

Comment: Regex - is a regular grammar. What you want usually done by utilizing either hardcoded automaton with stack (like suggested) or using frameworks to parse input according to LR/LL grammar: ANTLR, Gold, pegasus, etc. For example there is a ton grammars for ANTLR: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4. Using regex for anything other than regular structures (non-recursive) is a bad idea practially/scientifically: parsing html, expressions, etc is not regex scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong tools for the job. **.NET regex does not provide recursion**, in particular I'm not sure it even can recognise all CFGs, which is an interesting question in and of itself<sup>1</sup>. So if your question is of, emm, academic interest, then you're all good to read ahead. If you want to actually use this in some production code then *please* don't.

That being said, to match parentheses you can use [balancing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition). Adapting the example from the docs that matched angle brackets you'd get this:

```regex
^[^\(\)]*(((?'Open'\()[^\(\)]*)+((?'Close-Open'\))[^\(\)]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))$
```

What you can put inside the parentheses is defined by the expressions `[^\(\)]*` above. I was unsuccessful with trying to incorporate the number-AND/OR rules into this without losing my mind and creating a regex of length way beyond federal regulations.

However, we can verify your input using multiple regexes in conjunction. First, ignore the parentheses and make sure the expression is of general form `number (AND/OR number)*`:

```regex
^[\(\)]*([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)(\s(AND|OR)\s[\(\)]*([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)[\(\)]*)*$
```

Parentheses that are empty and parentheses with a single number are already excluded by the above pattern. It remains to exclude strings that use multiple AND/OR within a single parenthesis, like `1 OR 2 AND 3` or `1 OR (2 AND 3 AND 4)` or `1 AND 2 OR (1 AND 2)`.

```regex
(\d)+\s*(AND|OR)\s*(\d)+\s*(AND|OR)
```

So to validate your input you would run all three regexes and assert that the first two match while the last one does not.

By the way, you could probably use [alternation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#alternation-constructs) as a branching instruction and combine these three regexes into a single one that asserts a match with the first two and no-match with the last one. This is left as an exercise to the reader as that would again be beyond unreadable.

You can find a working dotnetfiddle demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qmM0Of). The code follows below for reference:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
var correctParantheses = new Regex(@"^[^\(\)]*(((?'Open'\()[^\(\)]*)+((?'Close-Open'\))[^\(\)]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))$");
var correctStructure = new Regex(@"^[\(\)]*([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)(\s(AND|OR)\s[\(\)]*([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)[\(\)]*)*$");
var ambiguousClauses = new Regex(@"(\d)+\s*(AND|OR)\s*(\d)+\s*(AND|OR)");

bool Validate(string input) => 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) && 
    correctParantheses.IsMatch(input) && 
    correctStructure.IsMatch(input) && 
    !ambiguousClauses.IsMatch(input);

var validInputs = new [] 
{
    "1 AND 2",
    "(1 AND 2) OR 3",
    "1 AND (2 OR 3)",
    "(1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)",
    "1 AND (2 OR (3 AND (4 OR 5)))",
    "((((1 AND 2) OR 3) AND 4) OR 5)",
    "1"
};

var invalidInputs = new [] 
{
    "(1 AND 2)) OR 3",
    "((1 AND 2) OR 3",
    "(1)",
    "()",
    "101",
    "1 AND AND 2",
    "AND 1 AND",
    "AND",
    "1 1 AND 2",
    "1 OR 2 AND 3",
    "1 OR (2 AND 3 AND 4)",
    "1 AND 2 OR (1 AND 2)"
};

foreach (var validInput in validInputs)
{
    var isValid = Validate(validInput);
    if (!isValid)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Valid input {validInput} did not validate.");
    }
}

foreach (var invalidInput in invalidInputs)
{
    var isValid = Validate(invalidInput);
    if (isValid)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Invalid input {invalidInput} validated.");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("All cases passed.");
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Intuitively it can, since balancing groups basically allow you to implement a stack and using backtracking there should be a way to achieve nondeterminism. But I don't have a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: That's awesome :).   It will take me some time to fully understand it but it's awesome. I think the regex themselfs are quite eloquent to show why it's not the best idea to use them in production ;)

Comment: There are several [regex engines that provide recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), but .NET regexes apparently do not.

Answer (score 0):

Regex - is a regular grammar. It parses regular and usually non-recursive structures, it is not meant in general to parse recursive structures like: JSON, HTML, math expressions, boolean expressions, C++, C#, Java, etc. It just doesn't fit with other kinds of grammars, regex works on finite state automaton, whereas your task involves context (this is why stack will be required), thus you should use next level of grammar hierarchy:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#The_Chomsky_hierarchy

What you want usually done by utilizing either hardcoded automaton with stack (like suggested in comments) or using frameworks to parse input according to LR/LL grammar: ANTLR, Gold, pegasus, etc.

For example there is a ton grammars for ANTLR: github.com/antlr/grammars-v4.
And if dig into grammars a little bit you will find there is answer to your question in multiple grammars:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4

Comment: There seems to be a `(?R)` synthax, it's more what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out. I value your time, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: C# have balancing groups, you could look into them, but be warned - this is abomination and your team will hate you for this. Use hardcoded version - it will take much less effort and much more gain.